# merging object files after compiling executable

Tags: linker, compilation, archive, object-files

i have an executable with many .o files. i would like to reduce these object files to one file but i don't have the source code for the executable. is archiving them using "ar" is the way to do it or is it impossible without recompiling the source?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly combine the object file with ar into a library. In addition, `ld -r` allows to combine multiple object files into a single one.